# Is generator-like querying of a database by sqlalchemy possible?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, generator

At the moment I query my database this way:

```
for author in session.query(Author).filter(Author.queried==0).slice(0, 1000):
    print "Processing:", author
    # do stuff and commit later on
```

This means every 1000 authors I have to restart the script.

Is it possible to make the script run endless (or as long as there are authors)? I mean by that, if it is possible to turn

```
session.query(Author).filter(Author.queried==0).slice(0, 1000)
```

into some sort of generator which yields **the next author for which `queried==0` is true**.

Answer (score 2):

Query objects can be treated as iterators as-is.  SQL will be executed once you start using data from the query iterator.  Example:

```
for author in session.query(Author).filter(Author.queried==0):
    print "Processing: ", author
```

Your question uses the word "endlessly", so a word of caution.  SQL is not an event-processing API; you cannot simply do a query that runs "forever" and spits out each new row as it is added to a table.  I wish that were possible, but it isn't.

If your intent is to detect new rows, you will have to poll regularly with the same query, and design an indicator into your data model that allows you to tell you which rows are new.  You seem to be representing that now with a `queried` column.  In that case, within the `for` loop above you might set `author.queried = 1` and `session.add(author)`.  But you can't `session.commit()` inside the loop.

Comment: If I don not commit, every thing would be lost if my script crashes... So it would be better to wrap the actual script by a while loop which keeps iterating as long as there are authors with `queried==0` true, correct?

Comment: A natural place to commit is just after your loop is done.  But if you have many changes, that could be a large transaction and not perform well.  If so, the slice in your original problem statement might actually be better.  It depends on exactly what you're doing and how many rows are likely to be returned.

Comment: As an update postgres has support for a listen/notify event api

Answer (score 0):

Since the query is turned into an equivalent SQL SELECT statement you will only be able to get the set of Author rows where queried is 0 that existed when this transaction started. Any updates to the Author queried column will not change the current SELECT set.

If you want to continue processing all the Author rows even if there are more than 1000 then you could do

```
for author in session.query(Author).filter(Author.queried==0):
    print "Processing:", author
```

The `__iter__` method on the Query object will called automatically which will return the same iterator as calling `instances` on the Query object.